# setting up UIWebView scrollView delegate causes an error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

So I have the following code:

```
 NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    if ([currSysVer compare:@"5.0" options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending) {
        webScrollView = self.webView_.scrollView;
    } else {
        webScrollView = [self.webView_ defaultScrollView];
    }

webScrollView.delegate = self
```

and when I scroll it gives me:

```
-[UIWebView scrollViewDidScroll:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e8610
```

this doesn't make any sense why the UIWebView is calling the scrollViewDidScroll\

Comment: Where are you allocating the webScrollView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), UIWebView conforms to UIScrollViewDelegate.  In essence it uses the same delegation, as UIWebView is scrollable (you might say it's a subclass of UIScrollView, though it's not explicitly stated in the documentation, likely a UIScrollView is a piece of the WebView).

Comment: Looking at your code some more, it would help to see where you're defining webScrollView and webView. Are you getting any warnings you're ignoring on any of these lines? Are you calling scrollViewDidScroll manually anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

The `UIWebView` HAS-A a `scrollView` of which it is the delegate, meaning the `scrollViewDidScroll`: method is implemented by the `UIWebView`, because you are using the reference the UIWebView provides to its `scrollView`, you are now saying that you will be handling this callbacks including `scrollViewDidScroll`:, and clearly you are not which is why when the delegate call happens it fails.

Why are you trying to assign as the delegate of the webview scrollview?, that behavior is already implemented. I am not sure it will play nice if you try to alter that behavior, but in either case if you want to be the delegate of the scrollView then you have to implement the `UIScrollViewDelegate`  protocol and then implement the required methods.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for all version

```
UIScrollView* sv = nil;
    for (UIView* v in  _webview.subviews) {
        if([v isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]){
            sv = (UIScrollView*) v;
            sv.scrollEnabled = NO;
            sv.bounces = NO;

    }
}
```